# Ad hominem for non persons

Tags: single-word-requests, meaning, word-usage, ambiguity, latin

An *ad hominem* argument is typically, according to Wikipedia, "a rhetorical strategy where the speaker attacks the character, motive, or some other attribute of the person making an argument rather than attacking the substance of the argument itself." It is in the name that this type of argument is an attack on a *person*.

What if the entity being attacked is not a person? Perhaps it's a legal entity like a business (and the 'argument' being made is about the quality of their offerings if you want to be pedantic). "The services offered by X are bad because their reviews are bad and they were fined recently for breaking a bunch of regulations." Or "don't trust Y, recall that Y used to be called Z but they rebranded to Y because their reputation was so bad." I'd give a real life example of the latter, but that might be a little... meta.

Does the term *ad hominem* still apply? Is there a better alternative?

Comment: There are several terms for specific subtypes of *ad hominem* arguments on [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ad_hominem) most of which don't refer to a man or a human being. I can't find any source saying *ad hominem* only applies to humans, or the opposite, but using a more specific term is a good idea.

Comment: 'Guilt by association' is probably broadened enough to be applied to entities other than individual humans. Even, metaphorically, agencies (like flu) lacking any quintessential involvement with sentience.

Comment: 'ad hominem' still applies, it's just a metaphor. Just like 'ad baculum' doesn't mean you are literally hitting someone with a stick. Of course, you  can use the association with 'man' to make a witticism, but it'll be a groaner.

Comment: Not every personal attack is an "ad hominem". It's only "ad hominem" if it's used [instead of a genuine argument](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ad_hominem#Improper_usage).

Answer (score -1):

The commenters have been kind to point out that the term 'ad hominem' is not incorrect in this context. But there are subtypes of *ad hominem* with their own names that avoid the association with 'man.' The examples in the question seem to me like cases of [poisoning the well](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Poisoning_the_well).

And if you happen to be American corporations are people in your country /shrug